mv with interaction in command terminal
I need to find and move a file in the Linux terminal, I already managed to do it with the following line
find . -name "*FILE*" -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} /FOLDER1/

but what I need is to ask if you want to move the file before doing it, I tried it with the -i flag but it only works when it is going to be overwritten.

I think you'll need to resort to using a higher level language or a more complex bash script to achieve this. You could touch each file in the target directory, prompt for a yes/no answer, mv if yes, rm the touched file if no.

Have you come up w/ a solution?

If mv -i does not do what you want, you should write a simple script that does behave the way you want and invoke it instead of mv.

To ask for confirmation before moving files, you can create a simple shell script that accomplishes this:
Script:
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the number of arguments is correct
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <search_term> <destination>" >&2
    exit 1
fi


SEARCH_TERM="$1"
DEST_FOLDER="$2"

if [ ! -d "$DEST_FOLDER" ]; then
    mkdir -p "$DEST_FOLDER" || { echo "Failed to create directory $DEST_FOLDER" >&2; exit 1; }
fi

exec 3<&0 # Open file descriptor 3 for user input

find . -name "*${SEARCH_TERM}*" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    echo "Move file: $file to $DEST_FOLDER? (y/n)"
    read -r response <&3
    if [[ "$response" =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]; then
        echo "Moving file $file to $DEST_FOLDER"
        mv "$file" "$DEST_FOLDER" || { echo "Failed to move file $file to $DEST_FOLDER" >&2; exit 1; }
    else
        echo "Skipped $file"
    fi
done

exec 3<&- # Close file descriptor 3

You can also add it to the path and make it a command,.
Save it in /bin and ensure it has executable permissions using chmod +x.

If a command fails, it should print an error message and exit non-zero.  if the usage statement is considered an error message (IMO, it should not be), it should be written to stderr. (eg echo >&2 ...).  If the usage statement is not considered an error message, you should exit 0.  Printing a usage statement to stdout and exiting non-zero is a terrible practice which needs to stop.

Yes, you are right. I will apply the changes. Thanks for your feedback.
